# OpenCV Python- Filter rectangles to find the centre line of a road for miniature cars

Tags: python, opencv, filter, rectangles

I'm trying to filter rectangles to find the centre line of a road for miniature cars and help them to 'see' the road. My overall goal is to write an AI so a human can race against the car controlled by the AI. As you can see the project is still in the early stages. I'm not quite sure if cv2.minAreaRect() is the right function for this. I also looked at cv2.boundingRect(). My idea now is to measure the size of the rectangles and filter the wrong ones out so only the centre line of the road is left. But I'm not sure if thats the best solution. I tried to visualize the centre line of the road  in red in the third picture for you. The centre line of the road is shown by the long trail of rectangles that look the same. 
Maybe you guys have an idea that could help. 
I will post my code so far and the image I worked on with the code. I will also post an image of how far I've come with the rectangles. Thank you for the help!

image to find the rectangles in:
[image: image to find the rectangles in]

after running my code:
[image: after running my code]

rectangles i want to keep:
[image: rectangles i want to keep]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
image = cv2.imread('Carrera.png')
cv2.waitKey(0)

# set grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# show gray image
cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# change contrast/brightness
alpha = 50  # Contrast control (0-100)
beta = 0  # Brightness control (0-100)
adjusted = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gray, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

# show high contrast image
cv2.imshow('Contrast', adjusted)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#  find canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(adjusted, 30, 200)

# set blur
blur = cv2.blur(edged, (3, 3))

# find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blur, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# show canny edges
cv2.imshow('Canny Edges', blur)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# number of contours found
print("Number contours = " + str(len(contours)))

# paint rectangles
for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

# show final image
cv2.imshow('Rectangles', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: could you please show us what you WANT to get, because it's very non-obvious from your code / explanation or images?

Comment: I tried to do it by adding a picture showing the centre line of the road from the rectangles when i run my code. These are the rectangles I want to keep. I hope that helps. Thank you for looking over it!

Answer (score 1):

You want to eliminate unnecessary rectangles by using their length. You already have those data via [minAreaRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect).

The output of it orderly which is holding `rect` in your code:

```
center    The rectangle mass center.
size      Width and height of the rectangle.
angle     The rotation angle in a clockwise direction.
```

Here is output and how you can use `rect` to eliminate unnecessary rectangles:

**Output**:

[image]

**Code to be added:**

```
# paint rectangles
for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    if(rect[1][0]<110 and rect[1][0]>40 and rect[1][1]<70 and rect[1][1]>40):
       cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you i will try that ! I also clarified my question so you can better see what rectangles are the centre line of the road. Its now visualized in the second picture.